# test what factors determine modelling performance

Tags: r, performance, statistics

I am analyzing the performance (estimation error) of a range of forecasting methods (population dynamics model).
To do so I applied each method on a range of population dynamics (model fits to different species), starting from 2 different years (performance might depend on how the species was doing at the time).
This gives an output similar to this:

```
df1 <- expand.grid(species=letters[1:3],
                       time=1:2,
                       method=LETTERS[11:13])
df1$error <- rnorm(nrow(df2),0,10)

    species time method error
1        a    1      K   3.93566373
2        b    1      K -26.95329369
3        c    1      K   3.68377329
4        a    2      K -21.68417747
5        b    2      K   6.59804377
6        c    2      K  -4.53913733
7        a    1      L  -6.94936825
8        b    1      L  -0.06846303
...
```

I am not really interested in the modelling performance for each species, but rather in the underlying factors.
Therefore, for each species I calculated a bunch of characteristics from the time at which I start the forecast:

```
df2 <- data.frame(species=rep(letters[1:3],2),
                  time=rep(1:2,each=3),
                  char1=c(rnorm(3,c(1:3),0.1),rnorm(3,c(1:3),0.1)),
                  char2=c(rnorm(3,c(100,200,300),20),rnorm(3,c(100,200,300),20)),
                  char3=c(rnorm(3,c(20,26,40),0.1),rnorm(3,c(20,26,40),0.1)))

    species time   char1     char2    char3
1       a    1 1.0573675 127.38703 20.06343
2       b    1 2.0849696 215.25302 26.04236
3       c    1 3.1334384 308.42294 39.97982
4       a    2 0.9499281  82.63552 19.99231
5       b    2 2.0510098 214.59121 26.06874
6       c    2 3.0868793 310.00532 40.01716
```

Note that most (but not all) characteristics are similar for the same species/population.
They are not significantly correlated (R2) but some are clearly dependend (e.g. standard deviation and temporal autocorrelation in the historical dynamcis). 
Some of the forecasting methods are more similar to others and their performance is hence not completely independent either.

How do I know which characteristics have the most influence on projection performance, in general and by method? 
For instance, char1 might largely determine performance of all projection methods, but could also especially influence method K. 
The idea is to find what method might best be used given a set of population characteristics.

I looked into several statistical techniques, but usually the assumptions are violated.
My best idea so far is to use a type of linear regression for each method separately (error ~ char1 + char2 +1|time) and make a table of for instance the deviances explained by each characteristic.

```
method   char1   char2   char3
K        5%      10%     3%
L        3%      20%     9%
M        0%      55%     6%
```

I feel however highly unsure about whether this is the right approach? What other statistical methods could I consider to answer my questions?

Thank you

Comment: This is a whole discipline in itself and cannot be answered easily. Perhaps this link will help you a bit: [link](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/effect-size/). In linear regression, the magnitude of the regression coefficients can usually give a good indication of the effect that each variable has on the outcome, though. If you want to be more precise and rigorous, you are probably going to have to dig quite deep into statistics literature. Spoiler alert: it is quite likely that after you understand everything, the only thing you know, is that you don't know ;-)

Comment: Thank you!! I learned something new through the link!